# we are trying to find most probable realization of random variable x, is this error in algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, random-variables, binomial-distribution

So the task says: Random variable X has binomial distribution, what is the most probable realization of random variable X?

so of course it must be p0 <= p1 <= ... <= pk and pk >= pk+1 >= ... pn. So they first divede pk and pk-1 than pk and pk+1. When dividing pk and pk+1 they get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCKf9.jpg . That is they find that k<=  (n+1) * p - 1 but i keep getting  k<= (n+1) * p - n. I know they replaced q with (1-p)  but I don't how did they got - 1 instead of - n, maybe my algebra is wrong but I don't know where did made a mistake.

Can someone please explain to me how did they gone from q*(n - k) >= p*(k + 1) to k >= (n+1)*p - 1 ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.